# Getting An Error When Trying To Configure A TFS Agent On Windows 10

Tags: tfs

I have a self-hosted TFS for which I am trying to configure an agent on a Windows 10 machine.  I run the configuration script. I enter the URL to my TFS instance, and I select the default authentication type.  The script attempts to connect, but it returns with the error message: "TFS Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required."

I can get to the URL I entered into the script through a web browser, so I know that the machine can access it. I used fiddler to monitor traffic, while the script was attempting to connect to the URL. Fiddler showed the URL (http://{mydomain}/_apis/connectionData?connectOptions=1&lastChangeId=-1&lastChangeId64=-1) that the script was trying to connect to. When I click it, the URL opens in the browser. When I enter in my credentials, I get a JSON response that I don't get when the script tries to access that URL. The script's request returns an error page, according to fiddler. The script never asks me for my credentials, unlike my attempt to access the URL in fiddler through the browser.

I did check the configuration of the authentication of the IIS website on which my TFS URL is hosted. It has anonymous access enabled, windows authentication enabled with NTLM as the the provider, and other methods are disabled. I did try adding Negotiate as a windows authentication provider but that did not fix the problem.

I'm at a loss, regarding how to move past this issue.  Any pointers, references, potential solutions, etc. would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Below is the code for the batch file that TFS provides for configuring an agent:

```
@echo off

rem ********************************************************************************
rem Unblock specific files.
rem ********************************************************************************
setlocal
if defined VERBOSE_ARG (
  set VERBOSE_ARG='Continue'
) else (
  set VERBOSE_ARG='SilentlyContinue'
)

rem Unblock the following types of files:
rem 1) The files in the root of the layout folder. E.g. .cmd files.
rem
rem 2) The PowerShell scripts delivered with the agent. E.g. capability scan scripts under "bin\"
rem and legacy handler scripts under "externals\vstshost\".
rem
rem 3) The DLLs potentially loaded from a PowerShell script (e.g. DLLs in Agent.ServerOMDirectory).
rem Otherwise, Add-Type may result in the following error:
rem   Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///[...].dll' or one of its dependencies.
rem   Operation is not supported.
rem Reproduced on Windows 8 in PowerShell 4. Changing the execution policy did not appear to make
rem a difference. The error reproduced even with the execution policy set to Bypass. It may be a
rem a policy setting.
powershell.exe -NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "$VerbosePreference = %VERBOSE_ARG% ; Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath '%~dp0' | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose ('Unblock: {0}' -f $_.FullName) ; $_ } | Unblock-File | Out-Null ; Get-ChildItem -Recurse -LiteralPath '%~dp0bin', '%~dp0externals' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\.(ps1|psd1|psm1)$' } | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose ('Unblock: {0}' -f $_.FullName) ; $_ } | Unblock-File | Out-Null ; Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath '%~dp0externals\vstsom', '%~dp0externals\vstshost' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\.(dll|exe)$' } | ForEach-Object { Write-Verbose ('Unblock: {0}' -f $_.FullName) ; $_ } | Unblock-File | Out-Null"

if "%~1" equ "remove" (
    rem ********************************************************************************
    rem Unconfigure the agent.
    rem ********************************************************************************
    "%~dp0bin\Agent.Listener.exe" %*
) else (
    rem ********************************************************************************
    rem Configure the agent.
    rem ********************************************************************************
    "%~dp0bin\Agent.Listener.exe" configure %*
)
```

Console Output from the agent:

```
>> Connect:

Enter server URL > http://{mydomain}/
Enter authentication type (press enter for Integrated) >
Connecting to server ...
TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.
Failed to connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit
Enter server URL > http://{mydomain}/
Enter authentication type (press enter for Integrated) > Negotiate
Enter user name > {myUserName}
Enter password > {myPassword}
Connecting to server ...
TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.
Failed to connect.  Try again or ctrl-c to quit
Enter server URL >
```

Stack trace from the log file:

```
[2020-04-13 16:18:39Z ERR  Terminal] Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssUnauthorizedException: TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__45.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__42`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.<GetConnectionDataAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.<ConnectAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.AgentServer.<ConnectAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.BuildReleasesAgentConfigProvider.<TestConnectionAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.<ConfigureAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Comment: **How** are you trying to authenticate? The error message is telling you that you're not providing valid credentials and are attempting to authenticate anonymously. It's not a configuration issue with TFS, it's a problem with how you're attempting to install the agent. You need to provide additional details.

Comment: @DanielMann I've attached the code to the script that TFS provides, if that helps

Comment: @user1062440 Which version of TFS are you using? What's the default authentication type when you config agent? Could you share the output when you run `config.cmd` after download the agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue, I went into my TFS. Opened up IIS. Went to the web application that hosts the TFS portal. Clicked on authentication. Opened up the providers for Windows Authentication. I added negotiate to listed and moved it ahead of NTLM. I reset the website on which the application resides. If negotiate is not ahead of NTLM, any connection to my server URL would treated as though I automatically cancelled the authentication prompt.

I went back to the machine that I wanted to configure the agent. I ran the configure script as administrator. I entered the server URL. I told the configuration script to use negotiate as the authentication type. I entered my credentials. The connection worked. The rest of the process proceeded as it should have.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried in an on-premise TFS deploying an agent, and found the default authentication type is `Integrated`, please try to use `negotiate` instead:

[image]

Comment: i tried using negotiate and got the same error. I added the console output and the stack trace from the log file. Also, I'm use TFS 2017.

Comment: I found `negotiate` won't work if your TFS use NTLM authentication type (you can check this in TFS administration console). But  default `Integrated` should work. It seemed that there were some old credentials stored which messed up the TFS build agent configuration on a particular machine. If you try on another client machine, how's the result? Please try to clear your browser history and cache, clear TFS caches `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache`, log out all TFS/DevOps in VS instances, and restart your machine.

Comment: This blog may give you some help: https://dankovalkov.wordpress.com/2017/08/29/tfs-2017-tf400813-resource-not-available-for-anonymous-access-client-authentication-required/